# How do I connect SpringBoot application running on host to Postgresql running on Docker?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

```
   ** Application.properties**
    
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0:8000/dockerDb
spring.datasource.password=somePassword
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

** docker ps**
CONTAINER ID  1506c2981b1d
IMAGE  13-version
COMMAND "docker-entrypoint.s…"
PORTS    5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->5438/tcp
NAMES    postgresql-13

Answer (score 0):

The 0.0.0.0 in the docker ps command means that any address can connect to the container. But you need to use a real IP address or machine name. As it's on the same computer, localhost will be fine:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:8000/dockerDb
```